# Get error message from imported/external validator to print django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am trying to build a simple user registration page. I want it to include a captcha for validation purposes. I am using django-simple-captcha for this purpose. (If there's a better library, tell me...)

So far everything is working great, EXCEPT that when a captcha is incorrect the user is not notified--they are simply returned to the registration screen. How can I get a specific ValidationError message printed when the captcha is invalid? (I'm also using django-crispy-forms, if that makes any difference)

template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Registration</legend>
        {{ form|crispy }}
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
      <small class="text-muted">Already Have An Account?<a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log in</a></small>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

form model:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
   email = forms.EmailField(validators=[validate_email])
   captcha = CaptchaField()

   class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2'] # including 'captcha here didn't seem to make a difference
```

and the view:

```
def register(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
   form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
      *do unrelated things*
      return redirect('login')
   else:
      form = UserRegisterForm()
   return render(request, 'register-template-url', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

from simplecaptcha.fields import CaptchaField----
    if you are importing CaptchaField like this it will work. If it not works just simply do 1 change as shown below

from simplecaptcha import captcha,captchaform

```
@captchaform('captcha')
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(validators=[validate_email])
    captcha = CaptchaField()

   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2','captcha']
```